# Como pegar 2 arrays PHP e juntar em 1 string

Tags: php, array

Tenho 2 arrays em PHP que vem de um formulário `$_POST['qtd']` e `$_POST['ing']`:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" } 
array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "a" [1]=> string(1) "b" }
```

Tem como, de alguma forma, juntar eles em uma variável que fosse assim?

```
$variavel = "(1,'a'), (2,'b')";
```

Com isso vou fazer um `INSERT` na tabela de MYSQL que deverá ficar assim:

```
INSERT INTO tabela (qtd, ing) VALUES (1,'a'), (2,'b');
```

Comment: Vai gerar um sql com isso? pelo menos tem cara.

Comment: E os parenteses fazem parte da *string*? poderia formatar exatamente como precisa do resultado?

Comment: isso, vou fazer um insert mysql, vai ficar assim: INSERT INTO tabela (qtd, ing) VALUES (1,a), (2,b);

Comment: No título fala que quer gerar uma string mas o resultado esperado é um array. Pode esclarecer ou editar a pergunta?

Comment: é, acho que o titulo nao ficou mt claro, vou editar, mas o que preciso é isso, pegar as 2 arrays, para fazer um insert no MYSQL

Comment: Então teu problema é outro, não apenas juntar em uma string. É provável que o @rray já esteja formulando uma resposta, mas é mais aconselhável utilizar [`prepared statements`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) por segurança e porque é mais prático mesmo. Está utilizando que extensão para fazer a conexão? PDO, mysqli ou alguma outra?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode usar `array_map()` para pegar os repectivos valores de cada array (par a par) e dentro da função anônima montar o formato e/ou sanitizar a string. Como o retorno da função é um novo array, use a função `implode()` para separar todos os elementos por vírigula na string gerada:

```
$arr1 = array(1,2,3);
$arr2 = array('a', 'b', 'c');

$valores = array_map(function($a, $b){ return sprintf("('%s', '%s')", $a, $b);}, $arr1, $arr2);

echo implode(',', $valores);
```

Saída:

```
('1', 'a'),('2', 'b'),('3', 'c')
```

Comment: deu certinho, valeu!

Answer (score 4):

Você tem:

```
$arr = [
    ['0', '1'],
    ['a', 'b']
];
```

Primeiro, precisamos associar os valores do primeiro *array* com os valores do segundo. Você consegue fazendo isso com a função `array_map`:

```
$pares = array_map(null, ...$arr);
```

Obtendo, assim:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => a
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => b
        )

)
```

Cada par precisará virar um array no formato `(1, a)`, então ao invés de `null` criamos uma função:

```
$pares = array_map(function (...$parameters) {
    return '(' . join(', ', $parameters) . ')';
}, ...$arr);
```

Obtendo, assim:

```
Array
(
    [0] => "(0, a)"
    [1] => "(1, b)"
)
```

Depois, só utilizar novamente o `join`:

```
$resultado = join(', ', $pares);
```

Obtendo a string `"(0, a), (1, b)"`.

Perceba que os valores `a` e `b` não possuem aspas, o que pode quebrar a sintaxe do seu SQL se não tratadas corretamente.